# EF Core Fluent API statement as Data Annotation

Tags: api, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, annotations, fluent

Can I write this with data annotations in EF Core?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DiagramComponent>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Compressor)
                .WithMany(c => c.Components);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create one more class:

```
public class DiagramComponentComponent
    {
        public int DiagramComponentId { get; set; }
        public int ComponentId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(DiagramComponentId))]
        public virtual DiagramComponent DiagramComponent { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(ComponentId))]
        public virtual Component Component { get; set; }
    }
```

and add attributes to existing classes:

```
public class DiagramComponent
    {
        public int CompressorId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(CompressorId))]
        [InverseProperty("DiagramComponents")]
        public virtual Compressor Compressor { get; set; }

[InverseProperty(nameof(DiagramComponentComponent.DiagramComponent))]
public virtual ICollection<DiagramComponentComponent> DiagramComponentComponents { get; set; }
    }
    public class Compressor
    {
        [InverseProperty(nameof(DiagramComponent.Compressor))]
        public virtual ICollection<DiagramComponent> DiagramComponents { get; set; }

    }
    public class Component
    {
[InverseProperty(nameof(DiagramComponentComponent.Component))]
public virtual ICollection<DiagramComponentComponent> DiagramComponentComponents { get; set; }

    }
```

and add to dbcontext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DiagramComponentComponent>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.DiagramComponent )
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.DiagramComponentId )
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
          .HasConstraintName("FK_DiagramComponentComponent_Component_Diagram");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Component)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ComponentId )
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_DiagramComponentComponent_Component");
            });
```

Comment: Where can I accept the answer? For my case only the InverseProperty is necessary.

Comment: You have to click "Check" sign just below the answer header and click Up arrow too

Comment: I have new annotation problem:                              modelBuilder.Entity<FirstClass>()
                .HasOne(f => f.SecondClass)
                .WithOne(s => s.FirstClass)
                .HasForeignKey<FirstClass>(f => f.SecondClassId); How to make this.

Comment: If it is short we could discuss it here or accept this answer and create new post. I will answer to you.

Comment: I think you better post the new question, while you are posting I will be preparing the answer.

Comment: Your answer is ready , but you have to accept this one.